# How to distribute custom app using Apple Business manager?

Tags: applications, apple-business

We trying to distribute the custom app using the apple business manager, we purchased the app in the business manager. And we are trying to add the device to the business manager account. We didn't find any documentation on 'How to add the device to the business manager?'.

Please guide us through the process of enrolling the device.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you do this by going into "Device Management Settings" and entering your Apple Customer Number as well as your reseller's ABM/DEP IDs. This means that when you purchase new devices from this reseller, they're automatically added to ABM.

You can read Apple's guide on this [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/apple-business-manager/asmef1c47493/1/web/1).

If you want to manually add a few devices to test with, you can do that too:

Install "Apple Configurator 2" from the App Store on a Mac. Connect the device to the Mac. You'll automatically be prompted on whether to enroll this device. When you have done so, it will appear in ABM under Devices and then "Devices added by Apple Configurator 2". You can assign it to a MDM server.

You can read Apple's guide on this [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/apple-business-manager/apd200a54d59/web).

Remember that you need to have an MDM solution in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Also you can create redeemable codes.

First create an ABM account for your client. Then assign the app from iTunes connect to that account.

Your client will be able to see the app in his profile. Create the number of license you need and redeem them on the AppStore.